# printf in RT thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, real-time

I am writing a multi-thread application in Linux.

There is no RT patch in kernel, yet I use threads with priorities.

On checking the time it takes to execute `printf` , I measure different values every time I measure, although it is done in the highest priority thread :

```
if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start))
{ /* handle error */ 
}

for(int i=0; i< 1000; i++)
   printf("hello world");

if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end))
{ 
 /* handle error */ 
}
elapsedSeconds = TimeSpecToSeconds(&end) - TimeSpecToSeconds(&start);
```

Why does `printf` change timing and in non deterministic way , i.e. each
How should `printf` be used with RT threads ?

Can it be used inside RT thread or should it be totally avoided ?

Is `write` to disk should be treated in the same way as `printf` ? Should it be used only in separate low priority thread ?

Answer (score 0):

`printf` under the hood triggers a non-realtime (even blocking) mechanism of the buffered IO.

It's not only non-deterministic, but opens the possibility of a [priority inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion).

You should be very careful using it from a real time thread (I would say totally avoid it.

Normally, in a latency bound code you would use a wait-free binary audit into a chain of (pre-allocated or memory mapped) ring buffers and flush them using a background lower priority thread (or even a separate process).